# Convert Python 3.x snippet to C#/LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, python-3.x

I want to sort elements of a `HashSet<string>` and join them by a `;` character.

Python interpreter version:

```
>>> st = {'jhg', 'uywer', 'nbcm', 'utr'}
>>> strng = ';'.join(sorted(s))
>>> strng
'ASD;anmbh;ashgg;jhghjg'
```

C# signature of a method I seek:

```
private string getVersionsSorted(HashSet<string> versions);
```

I can do this without using Linq, but I really want to learn it better.

Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you all; it was hard to chose a winner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Note that HashSets are unordered.*

### Simple slower version:

```
String.Join(";", versions.OrderBy(v => v).ToArray());
```

### Custom faster version:

```
versions.OrderBy(v => v).Join(";");

///<summary>Appends a list of strings to a StringBuilder, separated by a separator string.</summary>
///<param name="builder">The StringBuilder to append to.</param>
///<param name="strings">The strings to append.</param>
///<param name="separator">A string to append between the strings.</param>
public static StringBuilder AppendJoin(this StringBuilder builder, IEnumerable<string> strings, string separator) {
    if (builder == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("builder");
    if (strings == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("strings");
    if (separator == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("separator");

    bool first = true;

    foreach (var str in strings) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            builder.Append(separator);

        builder.Append(str);
    }

    return builder;
}
///<summary>Combines a collection of strings into a single string.</summary>
public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> strings, string separator) { return new StringBuilder().AppendJoin(strings, separator).ToString(); }
```

### Cute Faster Version

```
versions.OrderBy(v => v).Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), 
    (v, sb) => sb.Append(sb.Length > 0 ? ";" : "").Append(v)
).ToString();
```

### .Net 4.0 fastest version:

```
String.Join(";", versions.OrderBy(v => v));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the option of using .NET 4.0, you could be using the [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) class to begin with, which would simplify things greatly, as you just need to call `string.Join` on your set then.

Otherwise, if you are restricted to .NET 3.5 as it seems, try the following:

```
private string GetVersionsSorted(ISet<string> versions)
{
    return string.Join(",", versions.OrderBy(s => s).ToArray());
}
```

(Note: if you were using .NET 4.0 you can also leave out the call to `ToArray`, which is handy.)

Comment: Cool ... switching to 4.0 soon.

Comment: By the way, where does ISet<string> come from? This is what in-VS2008 help gives me: public class HashSet<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable, ISerializable, IDeserializationCallback

Comment: `ISet<T>` is new to .Net 4.0.

Comment: Oops, yeah. `ISet<T>` is new to .NET 4.0 too... I forgot how much of the code I write these days is not backwards compatible with earlier versions of .NET heh! You can get away with using `IEnumerable<T>` though...

Comment: What are the advantages of having ISet<T>? Why did MSFT introduce it? Because it specifies the type more precisely?

Comment: @Hamish: It's for a similar reason as `ICollection<T>` and `IList<T>`. It represents a common interface (contract) for all set-like classes. It becamse particularly relevant when the BCL got `HashSet` *and* `SortedSet`, so they can have a common basis.

Answer (score 2):

```
HashSet<string> hash = new HashSet<string>(new string[] { "b", "a", "d" });
string output = hash.OrderBy(str => str).Aggregate((a, b) => a + ";" + b);
```

output: a;b;d

Answer (score 0):

```
var versions = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "jhg", "uywer", "nbcm", "utr" });
var result = string.Join(";", versions.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray());
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Please leave comment when down-voting, or even better modify the answer if you feel there's something wrong with it.

Comment: I honestly am not sure why your answer was down-voted. IT SEEMS OK TO ME.